# How can I position my progress bar at the bottom of a button?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I am facing a bit of an issue and I can't seem to figure it out.

I am trying to create a button and add a bootstrap progress bar at the bottom of it, but I cant seem to figure out how to get it to do just that.

Here's my current setup. https://jsfiddle.net/bob_mosh/7qeazm9w/3/

HTML:

```
<button id="sample_button" type="button" class="soundButton">
<label class="buttonTitle">Bird Song</label>
<label class="buttonDescription">A nice bird song.</label>
<div class="progress volume-slider">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.soundButton {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.650);
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px !important;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: none !important;
    float: left !important;
}

.soundButton label {
    color: rgba(37, 38, 43, 1.00) !important;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(37, 38, 43, 1.00)
}

.buttonTitle {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: block;
}

.volume-slider {
    bottom:0;
    height: 8px !important;
}
```

This is the current state on the right and the way I am envisioning it on the left.
[image: Wanted result on the left, actual result on the right.]

For some reason I cant get the absolute positioning to work. Every time I try to set the position of the progress bar to absolute, it completely disappears. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Do you want the progress bar  to appear below button and iutside the button structure?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/tz4f5m38/2/

are you expecting above result?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't completely clear there, I want the button to sit on the bottom edge of the button, not be outside of the button.

Comment: Remove the padding of the button, and set the padding only for the text

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/y6x18ogw/1/
See if it is expected result?

Comment: If you want to use position absolute then below is solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/y6x18ogw/3/

Comment: @bob_mosh check my answer

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I figured out a solution thanks to your help!

Comment: @Mangesh I'd add an `overflow: hidden` to the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add `position: relative;` to your `.soundButton` class then copy this to your `.volume-slider`

```
.volume-slider {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 8px !important;
}
```

Working sample fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/fvhswLma/)

Answer (score 1):

Reviewed your code on JsFiddle. I made some changes to it, please review:

```
<div class="progress progress-bottom">
<div class="progress-bar progress-child" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progress-bottom {
  position: relative;
  left: -8px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

This allowed me to get the progress bar at the bottom. Like this: [image: Please click and view the screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Long story short:

Absolute positioning works only inside of a relative container. I created a container in your html that only does that. I basically only set it to `position:relative` and then I used `position:absolute;` on the element inside of it. It disappears because `absolute` positioning removes the element from the flow. So other elements don't know it exists and basically gets stuck inside the first relative element it finds up the dom. If it doesn't, it goes 'poof'.

Read about positioning [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)

```css
.soundButton {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.650);
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px !important;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: none !important;
    float: left !important;
}

.soundButton label {
    color: rgba(37, 38, 43, 1.00) !important;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(37, 38, 43, 1.00)
}

.buttonTitle {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: block;
}

.volume-slider {
    bottom:0;
    height: 8px !important;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.progress-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button id="sample_button" type="button" class="soundButton">
<label class="buttonTitle">Bird Song</label>
<label class="buttonDescription">A nice bird song.</label>
<div class="progress-container">
  <div class="progress volume-slider">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
</div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Turns out I had to add another div to make it work. The working code looks like this:

```
<button id="sample_button" type="button" class="soundButton">
  <div class="buttonWrapperInside">
    <label class="buttonTitle">Bird Song</label>
    <label class="buttonDescription">A nice bird song.</label>
  </div>
  <div class="progress volume-slider">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
</button>
```

```
.progress {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) !important;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.progress-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
}

.soundButton {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.650);
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px !important;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: none !important;
    float: left !important;
}

.soundButton label {
    color: rgba(37, 38, 43, 1.00) !important;
}

.volume-slider {
    bottom:0px;
    height: 8px !important;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
}

.buttonWrapperInside {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

This works!

Thanks so much for your help guys there were a lot of pointers that helped me get there! Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: you don't necessarily need to add a div and a lot of stuff to achieve what you want. Checkou my answer.